# How can I display an image for a predetermined amount of time?

Tags: java, slick

I want to display an image, then return to the previous after one second when a certain key is pressed. I'm using Slick2d and Java. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: How much have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display the image you just need to keep track of some "elapsed time" variable and update it by the delta time each frame.  When that elapsed time variable hits whatever time limit you want, then you switch the image back.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer for this, and make sure to connect its timeOut -- or similar -- method to the method responsible for switching between images.

Inside the key press event handler you check whether the timer is already running, if not, start it and it's done.